# Speed per second on update interval less than a second

Tags: algorithm, time, bandwidth

[image]

Let's, for example here, look at this widget. It reads from `sysfs`, more precisely the files:

```
/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/tx_bytes
/sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/rx_bytes
```

And displays the bandwidth in Megabits per **second**. Now, the drill is, the widget is set to update every 1/4 of a second, 250ms. How, can the widget them calculate speed **per second**, if a second did not pass? Does is multiply the number it gets with 4? What's the drill?

Comment: seems like it width/(1/4) = 4*width

Comment: Yes, It's simple math. But that is not an accurate representation of the bandwidth, I assume.

Comment: It probably averages over several samples otherwise the number would fluctuate too quickly to observe.  `Average ( n samples at 250ms spacing) x 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values read from `tx_bytes` and `rx_bytes` are always current. The Widget just has to read the values every 250 ms and memorize at least the last 4 values. On each update, the difference between the current value and value read 1 second ago can be taken, divided by 125.000 and correctly be reported as the bandwidth in Megabits per second.